# How to get clicked item position from Custom ListView in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to get the position of the custom list view (after sorted from original list position). It is because the database id of the list item matches the position of the listview item. so, i need to get the sorted item's correct position matching the listview item position. I have this code.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sampleArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

But i m struck out that i need to get that position into my main activity. Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you mean the position of clicked item?

Comment: could you provide some more details and code.Whether you need to get  position while clicking item in list view?

Comment: ya. I need the position of clicked item but the position changed after sorting.

Comment: Which position you want? Row position of in database or row position in listview after sorting?

Comment: ya. I need the row position of the list item after sorting. I use to match the row position of the listview item with the database position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt,I completely understand your problem and what you want exactly.But i can suggest you that you can maintain HashMap for storing position-id pairs for each listview.

in your CustomAdapter:

```
public static HashMap<Integer,String> myList=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

in getView():

```
String id= (fetch _id from database);
myList.put(position, id);
```

And now in your main acitivity,you can retrieve _id of each listitem by putting this line in onClick() of OnItemClickListener():

```
 Long id=Long.parseLong(CustomAdapter.myList.get(position));
```

Comment: why should we get the database id in getview? we can get it in main activity itself na? any special use of it?

Comment: That would bind the position of your listitem with the _id of the database attached to that item.So it would be easy for you to work onto that record while listening to item click.

Comment: This would let you get correct _id of a listitem clicked,at whatever position,listitem is... Try this.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a field in the custom adapter mCurrentPosition, set it int the method

```
View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {<
this.mCurrentPosition = position;
....
}
```

Access this field from the activity.

Comment: I did as u said. It is showing only the last position of the list view. what ever i click the last position is selected.