# fix item of listview after list item is at sorted position

Tags: android, listview

Trying to make a sorting listview ,when the particular item is at its sorted place i want fix it,that is i want disable that particular item
what i tried is [Draggable Listview item on click disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426471/draggable-listview-item-on-click-disable.And) also i tried [enter link description here][1]Can any one explain where i m wrong

[1]: [How to get clicked item position from Custom ListView in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004774/how-to-get-clicked-item-position-from-custom-listview-in-android) ,my getview and myonitemclicklistener are

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    boolean isConverted = true;

    if (view == null) {

        Log.v("talkinginterval", "create view " + position);

        view = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, parent, false);
        isConverted = false;
    }

    modifyView(position, view, isConverted);

    for (int i = 0; i < mTo.length; i++) {
            View v = view.findViewById(mTo[i]);
        String from = mFrom[i];
         String data = mDataProvider.getItem(position);
       Long strId =mDataProvider.getItemId(position);
         Log.d("AstrId", "strId="+strId);
         Log.d("A", "mDataProvider.getItem(position)="+mDataProvider.getItem(position));

        String d = data.toString();

        myList.put(position, strId);

        boolean bound = false;
        if (mViewBinder != null) {
        bound = mViewBinder.setViewValue(view, v, d, from);
        }

        if (!bound) {

        if (v instanceof TextView) {

            ((TextView) v).setText(d);

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a "
                + " view that can be bounds by this Adapter");
        }
        }

    and


mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                String playerChanged = c.getText().toString();
                Log.d("A", "" + "Item clicklistener" + pos);

                mDraggableListView.setDragStatus(true);

                if (pos == 0) {
                            Log.d("A0", "" + "Item clicklistener" + pos);
                    // mDraggableListView.setDragStatus(false);

                }/*
                 * else{ mDraggableListView.setDragStatus(true); }
                 */

                Long myid = GenericAdapter.myList.get(pos);
                Log.d("Afinal", "myid"+myid);
            }

        });
```

Comment: and   public static HashMap<Integer,Long> myList = new HashMap<Integer, Long>(); is myList

Comment: Your question is vague. Please make it more clear before people vote to close it.